# Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException:

Tags: jmeter

Hi im trying to generate a html report but im getting an error

```
    Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :No column <responseMessage> found in sample metadata <timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;threadName;success;bytes;sentBytes;grpThreads;allThreads;URL;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname;IdleTime;Connect>, check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column
    ... end of run
```

my sript is

```
sh jmeter -n -t /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/testing.jmx -l /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/testingresult.csv -e -o /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/newf/
```

[image: here]

my newf is empty but im generating the cvs.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it self-explanatory? JMeter expects `responseMessage` column to be present in your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and it is not there.

Try amending your command as follows:

```
sh jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -n -t /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/testing.jmx -f -l /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/testingresult.csv -e -o /Users/johnnatividad/Desktop/loadtestfolder/newf/
```

If it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
```

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)